# SCons Custom Builder flag

Tags: builder, flags, scons

We use boost in our project which we build from source via a Command builder. But I've run into a problem on platforms where we support multiple different builds. i.e. On a Linux machine we support a Linux & Android version of boost.

Here if I run an Android build followed by a Linux build the builder does rebuild. i.e. Because the target & source file names are the same (even though the binaries are not).

I want to make my builder aware of which version of boost is being built. I'd like to use something similar to the CPPDEFINES variable. Whenever the value of this variable changes on a Program or Library the targets are rebuilt.

Is this possible? So far the best idea I've had is to use a scanner's path parameter. But that does not look correct.

How can I create a builder specific variable that SCons should use (like the sources & targets) to trigger a build. i.e. Rebuilding boost because MYVARIABLE has changed.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to create a builder specific variable that SCons could use (with some trickery added) to decide which version of the software it should build.
You're looking for "variant builds" as described in the UserGuide ( http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html ) , chap. 15 "Separating Source and Build Directories". This will enable you to create several "variants" (different PATH, CPPPATH, whatever, settings) in parallel (full support for "-j"), from the same sources.
This is the intended scheme for the build task as you describe it, and every other hack that looks tempting at first may lead to trouble later.

Please also stay away from using the VariantDir() method directly, use the "variant_dir=" option of the SConscript() call instead (see sect. 15.1 in UserGuide).